# Sort/Order Locations

Tags: c#, geospatial

I have a map with locations as shown in the image below.

[image]

These locations are held in a C# Dictionary object with both Latitude/Longitude and Cartesian (x, y, z) coordinates.  The area is covered by 5 teams, the first of which is in the south west of the area.  What I need is to be able to order the points so that the most south westerly point is first - this would be the green '3' marker near Enniskillen on the map.  I've been trying different approaches but not getting the result I want.

Can anyone explain an approach that would work?

Mark

Comment: Which approaches did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the Lat / Long of the South West corner of this map, I would calculate the distance of each point from that corner using the [Aviation Formulary](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist).  Then you just have to sort based on the distance calculated.

Comment: I was already using this formula to calculate straight line distance - but out of everything I tried it never occurred to me to pick a point on the south west corner and sort from there!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define "most south westerly" in a way similar to "most southerly", you could order the points `(x,y)` by `x+y`. You can think of this as moving a NW-SE line across the map from the SW corner, noting the order that the points are reached. This is equivalent to defining "most southerly" by sorting on `y`, where you're moving an east-west line up from the south edge and noting the order that you reach each point.

Comment: Hi, I'm not really following what you've said.  When I sort on x+y, it will give the green '3' marker near Enniskillen.  However if I remove this, I'd expect to get the green '4' marker near Enniskillen.  I actually get the green '1' marker near Coleraine at the top of the map.  Could you provide some pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Haversine formula to determine the distance between some location in the southwest corner of the map and each of the points. Here's a link with some code for both C# and Sql Server to do that very thing.

http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/